# Android - How to change default payment method in Braintree

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

In my Android application I am using Braintree payment SDK for payment. In my application user can add 5 credit cards to Braintree. I want to make first created card is as user default payment method and other are option cards. But my app make the last added card is as user default payment method.

**How can I change first card in default and other are option payment methods in Braintree.**

1. I done get credit card information from user, add into Braintree.
2. Get Nonce token from Braintree for the added card.
3. I will pass the nonce token to server team, they will pay using nonce token.

Code for above steps:

```
CardBuilder cardBuilder = new CardBuilder();
cardBuilder.cardNumber(getCardNumber());
cardBuilder.expirationMonth(getExpirationMonth());
cardBuilder.expirationYear(getExpirationYear());
cardBuilder.cvv(getCvv());
// get nonce token here.
nonce = mBraintreeApi.tokenize(cardBuilder);
```

I know first payment method creation as user default payment method and how can I

Comment: According to Braintree's documentation, the first payment method created will be the default. Are you passing in options when you create the new payment method that makes it default?

Comment: No I am not passing any option when create a new payment. How can I use option when create a new payment?

Comment: Are you seeing the default payment method being default on Braintree's side, or are you sending the wrong nonce token for payment?